# How to get window name from parent window in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I can get parent window name in Javascript, and don't know how to do it in Dart.
I have tried to down cast window.opener to window in Dart, but it throw exception.
According [html5.1 nightly](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#the-window-object%20w3c), should we expect it implemented as window basic attribute?

```
//js version:
window.opener.name
```

```js
//dart version:
(window.opener as ?).name
```

Comment: Can you please add the JS code to make it more clear what you are asking for?

Answer (score 1):

For a popup `window.opener` can be used and for an iframe `window.parent`. Both return a `_DOMWindowCrossFrame` which do not support `name` as they implement `WindowBase`. That's also the reason why you can't cast to `window`. You should use `postMessage` to communicate and exchange information.

See also this [implementation note](http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/tools/dom/src/dart2js_DOMImplementation.dart): *Its fields and methods can only be accessed via JavaScript.*

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use dart-js-interop

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

print(new js.JsObject.fromBrowserObject(
    js.context['window'])['opener']['name']);
```

There is currently no way in Dart. Access to the windows object is intentionally denied for security reasons. According to comments on related bug reports they consider changing it because it can be worked around using dart-js-interop anyway.

Comment: I am now using this approach, but feel uncomfortable with js route

Comment: There is currently no other way. See my updated answer.